# Facebook Customer Chat Plugin For React with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, facebook, typescript, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-customer-chat

I am developing a website with react and typescript and I want to include the Facebook customer chat plugin. I found this Node module https://github.com/Yoctol/react-messenger-customer-chat. Which seems like it would do the trick.

However there are no @types node module available for it. So I can't use it with typescript. I tried declaring my own d.ts declaration file however it's going over my head and I am unable to do so. Should I keep trying to learn how to create a d.ts declaration for it, if so how? Please point me to the right direction. Otherwise is there an alternative to include the customer chat plugin in a react app.

Answer (score 0):

One Solution I Found: A simple //@tsignore by the import and then use it as normal